# CLI for stop domain/host controller

Tags: jboss-eap-7

I am searching a command for stopping domain/host controller for eap7 but failed to find any answer, is there any command line beyond kill for it?

Best regards

Lan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to just stop the servers you can use:

```
/:stop-servers
```

If you want to shutdown the host controller and all the servers (assuming the default configuration here)

```
/host=master:shutdown
```

If you're using a different host name just replace `master` with that host name.