# JBoss-host-controller service stuck in "Stopping" status

Tags: jboss

[image: ![](https://lemmy.ml/pictrs/image/f061765c-1439-43fd-99da-57115b409dd6.png)]

I tried to stop the host controller, but it is stuck in the Stopping status... How can I force it to stop and restart?

I have looked at this post: [CLI for stop domain/host controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49249671/cli-for-stop-domain-host-controller) but I'm afraid of stopping everything. How do I only stop the JBoss-host-controller?

Answer (score 0):

After realizing the problem was with the Windows services and not the JBoss controller, I did some more research and found instructions:

1. Get the Service Name - for me it was `JBoss-host-controller`, but you can also double-click on the service to see its name.
2. Open a cmd and run `sc queryex JBoss-host-controller` to get the PID.
3. Copy the PID and run `taskkill /f /pid <PID>`
4. Go back to services, Right-click the service and Refresh, and the Stopping status should be gone, and you can start it again.

---

Here's the source:

https://4it.com.au/kb/article/how-to-kill-a-windows-service-which-is-stuck-at-stopping/